# Need help understanding vector identity

Tags: vector-analysis

Been trying to figure this out for hours now and finally came here for help. According to Wikepedia: $\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B}) = (\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})$. Can someone convince me how $(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A} \neq \mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})$? Because the dot product is commutative, so shouldn't it just equal $0$? Thanks

Comment: But what does $\nabla\mathbf B$ mean when $\mathbf B$ is a vector field and not a scalar function? And how do you dot it with $\mathbf A$?

Comment: $(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A}$ means contracting $\mathbf{A}$ with the $\mathbf{B}$ in the rank-2 tensor $\nabla\mathbf{B}$, whereas $\mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})$ means contracting $\mathbf{A}$ with the $\nabla$ in $\nabla\mathbf{B}$.  There is no reason to expect equality.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail. What do you mean by rank-2 tensor. Any resources to learn this?